# OracleTypes Compilation is forcing the application server restart

Tags: java, jdbc, struct, connection-pooling, oracle-type

Using the `Struct` object to send the data from java to Data base Stored Procedure.

For this Need `StructDescriptor` class, Creating using below code.

```
StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(sqlTypeName, conn);
```

In My spring application, When i executed this statement very first time.
the above statement is returning the `structDescriptor` object at the same time it is keeping in the connection object.

As i saw in `StructDescriptor` class code (API Code),

```
((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) conn).putDescriptor(qualifiedName, descriptor);
```

Second time onwards, Same connection is getting used, and the object is coming from connection object (not created freshly).

So, Mean while if i compile the object type in data base and call the Store Procedure is throwing the exception saying

```
invalid data type..
```

Here, I don't want to get the `StructDescriptor` Object from Connection. Instead of getting from connection Object again it needs to be created freshly. I may required that each time, before calling the below statement, better to remove the descriptors from connection object.  But I couldn't

```
StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(sqlTypeName, conn);
```

..

**How to remove descriptors from connection (getting from connection pool)?**